# How to build url parameter for checkbox value

Tags: html, forms, url, parameters

I am trying to pass value via url for two checkboxes, both with different names and only need to see if they are checked or unchecked.  Here is what the html code looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="one" value="one" checked id="one" >
<input type="checkbox" name="two" value="two" id="two" >
```

how do I encode this in url, so that the check boxes can be checked or unchecked by what's in the url, for example:

```
www.site.com?one=unchecked&two=checked
```

Comment: Do you have a server side scripting language or do you want to achieve it client side?

Comment: If you set your html form mode to GET, the form variables will be passed on the Url.  It produce exactly what you're showing, but if you have control over the server-side of things, you have the information (implicitly).  If this isn't on track, could you please clarify the parameters of the question?

Comment: I need to do this on the client side in the browser, not using the server side script.

Cj, what I am trying to do is to be able to set checkbox to either checked or unchecked using the value from the url.  For example, if the value for one is unchecked, the box will be unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a little php:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="one" value="one" id="one" <?= ($_GET["one"] == "checked" : "checked" : "" ?> >
<input type="checkbox" name="two" value="two" id="two" <?= ($_GET["two"] == "checked" : "checked='checked'" : "" ?>>
```

.... or as you mentioned it, on the client side with Javascript:

```
document.body.onload = function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash().substr(1);
    var parts = hash.split("&");
    for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var variable = parts.split("=");
        if(variable[0] == "one") // if the key of a get-variable equals "one"
            document.getElementById("one").setAttribute("checked");
        else if(variable[0] == "two") // if the key of a get-variable equals "two"
            document.getElementById("two").setAttribute("checked");
    }
};
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks atreju.  If I have the above javascript on my page, how would I transfer that to the next page via url?  What I am trying to do is when the link is clicked, I want that value to be passed to the next page <a href='www.site.com?box-one=unchecked&box-two=checked'>link</a>

Is that possible?